# How to save ArrayList state inside method?

Tags: arraylist, methods

I have an Arraylist inside method:

```
Activity{
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    ArrayList<Drink> mDrinkList = new ArrayList<>();
    mDrinkList.add (new Drink("water", 100));
  }
}
```

Question is: how to save items that was added to `mDrinkList` during previous usages of method? This method creates new ArrayList each time, so it always contains one last added item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare **mDrinkList** variable outside of the method if you want its values to persist. so `ArrayList<Drink> mDrinkList = new ArrayList<>();` needs to be given outside of the `onOptionsItemSelected` method.

you can learn more about scope of variables and declarations from here :
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/global-local-variables-python/

Hope this helps.